# Is it possible to change default system displaying for F4 help programmatically?

Tags: abap, sap-erp, netweaver

​Is it possible to change system defaults for F4 help in SAP NetWeaver without administration rights programmatically?. I mean from Dialog(modal) to Control (amodal) . Or for example using own f4 help created in dictionary? If it is possible, in which sap standard table the changes for system (not current user) are stored?

Comment: alv and dynpros

Comment: not clear which default you are talking about. And formulate your questions more clearly: default system and systems default are totally different concepts